# Loop over array dimension in plpgsql

Tags: database, postgresql, for-loop, multidimensional-array, plpgsql

In plpgsql, I want to get the array contents one by one from a two dimension array.

```sql
DECLARE
  m varchar[];
  arr varchar[][] := array[['key1','val1'],['key2','val2']];
BEGIN
  for m in select arr LOOP
    raise NOTICE '%',m;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

But the above code returns:

```
{{key1,val1},{key2,val2}}
```

in one line. I want to be able to loop over and call another function which takes parameters like:

```
another_func(key1,val1)
```

Answer (score 150, accepted):

#### Since PostgreSQL 9.1

There is the convenient **`FOREACH`** which can loop over **slices** of arrays. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY):

> The target variable must be an array, and it receives successive
> slices of the array value, where each slice is of the number of
> dimensions specified by `SLICE`.

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   m   text[];
   arr text[] := '{{key1,val1},{key2,val2}}';  -- array literal
BEGIN
   FOREACH m SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'another_func(%,%)', m[1], m[2];
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=865ca9823a5a3c2dd6207f07c6f6b4bf)* - with a function printing results, instead of `DO`

`LANGUAGE plpgsql` is the default for a `DO` statement so we can omit the declaration.

There is no difference between `text[]` and `text[][]` for the Postgres type system. See:

- [Initial array in function to aggregate multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832973/initial-array-in-function-to-aggregate-multi-dimensional-array/9845460#9845460)

#### Postgres 9.0 or older

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   arr text[] := array[['key1','val1'],['key2','val2']];  -- array constructor
BEGIN
   FOR i IN array_lower(arr, 1) .. array_upper(arr, 1)
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'another_func(%,%)', arr[i][1], arr[i][2];
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

Comment: How do we run this dynamically, for eg if we have array arr with n items, we need to raise notice n time for each item.

Comment: @CherrylRarewings: I suggest you start a new question with your specifics. You can always link to this one for context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FOREACH` statement to iterate a 2D array as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  temp VARCHAR;
  _2d_arr VARCHAR[] := ARRAY[
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['d','e','f']
  ];
BEGIN
  FOREACH temp SLICE 0 IN ARRAY _2d_arr LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', temp;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Or, you can use a `FOR` statement to iterate a 2D array as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  _2d_arr VARCHAR[] := ARRAY[
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['d','e','f']
  ];
BEGIN
  FOR num1 IN 1..2 LOOP
    FOR num2 IN 1..3 LOOP
      RAISE INFO '%', _2d_arr[num1][num2];
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Then, you can iterate the 2D array as shown below:

```
INFO:  a
INFO:  b
INFO:  c
INFO:  d
INFO:  e
INFO:  f
DO
```