# Initial array in function to aggregate multi-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array, aggregate-functions

I have a table with arrays of integer.

I want to create an aggregate function that will return a 2-dimensional array with all the rows together. It then gets passed to `plr` to do some maths on it.

I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION arrayappend(left int[][], right int[]) 
RETURNS int[] AS 
$BODY$
   SELECT $1 || $2 ;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

and:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_sum2 (int[])  (
    SFUNC     = arrayappend,
    STYPE     = int[][],
    INITCOND  = '{}'
);
```

But the return type is `int[]`, not `int[][]`?

How can I initialize the aggregate with an empty two dimensional array of integer?

Answer (score 10):

### Postgres 9.5 or newer

... ships with an additional variant of the aggregate function `array_agg()`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)

> input arrays concatenated into array of one higher dimension (inputs
>   must all have same dimensionality, and cannot be empty or null)

So not exactly the same as the custom aggregate function `array_agg_mult()` below. But use it, if you can. It's faster.

Related:

- [How to sort two dimensional int array in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853198/how-to-sort-two-dimensional-int-array-in-postgresql/30854193#30854193)

### Postgres 9.4 or older

#### Aggregate function for *any* array type

With the [polymorphic type `anyarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) it works for all kinds of arrays (including `integer[]`):

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult (anyarray) (
   SFUNC     = array_cat
 , STYPE     = anyarray
 , INITCOND  = '{}'
);
```

As @Lukas provided, the custom function `arrayappend()` is not needed. The built in [`array_cat()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) does the job. However, that doesn't explain *why* your example fails, while the one in Lukas' answer works. The relevant difference is that Lukas nested the array into another array layer with `array[d.a]`.

You trip over the incorrect assumption that you could declare a type `int[][]`. But you cannot: `int[][]` is the **same type** as `int[]` for the PostgreSQL type system. The [chapter on array types in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION) explains:

> The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of
>   dimensions either. Arrays of a particular element type are all
>   considered to be of the same type, regardless of size or number of
>   dimensions. So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in
>   `CREATE TABLE` is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time behavior.

An `n`-dimensional integer array effectively is an array of `n-1`-dimensional arrays of integer in PostgreSQL. You can't tell that from the type which only defines the **base element**. You have to ask [`array_dims()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) to get the specifics.

To demonstrate:

```
SELECT array_agg_mult(arr1)               AS arr1  --> 1-dim array
     , array_agg_mult(ARRAY[arr1])        AS arr2  --> 2-dim array
     , array_agg_mult(ARRAY[ARRAY[arr1]]) AS arr3  --> 3-dim array
       -- etc.
FROM  (
   VALUES
      ('{1,2,3}'::int[])                           -- 1-dim array
    , ('{4,5,6}')
    , ('{7,8,9}')
   ) t(arr1);
```

Or:

```
SELECT array_agg_mult(arr2)        AS arr2  --> 2-dim array
     , array_agg_mult(ARRAY[arr2]) AS arr3  --> 3-dim array
     , array_agg(arr2)             AS arr3  --> 3-dim array; superior in Postgres 9.5+
FROM  (
   VALUES
      ('{{1,2,3}}'::int[])                  -- 2-dim array
     ,('{{4,5,6}}')
     ,('{{7,8,9}}')
   ) t(arr2);
```

*All* resulting columns are of the same *type*: `int[]` (even though containing a different number of dimensions).

Answer (score 2):

Using the built-in array_cat function works.

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_sum2 (int[])  (
    SFUNC     = array_cat,
    STYPE     = int[],
    INITCOND  = '{}'
);
```

test:

```
select array_sum2(array[d.a]) from (select array[1,1,2,3] as a union select array[5,8,13,21] as a) d;
       array_sum2        
-------------------------
 {{1,1,2,3},{5,8,13,21}}
```