# Is there something like a zip() function in PostgreSQL that combines two arrays?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have two array values of the same length in PostgreSQL:

`{a,b,c}` and `{d,e,f}`

and I'd like to combine them into

`{{a,d},{b,e},{c,f}}`

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Postgres 9.5 or later

has [**`array_agg(array expression)`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.1.1.1.1):

> `array_agg` ( `anyarray` ) → `anyarray`
>
> Concatenates all the input arrays into an array of one higher
> dimension. (The inputs must all have the same dimensionality, and
> cannot be empty or null.)

This is a drop-in replacement for my custom aggregate function `array_agg_mult()` demonstrated below. It's implemented in C and considerably faster. Use it.

### Postgres 9.4

Use the `ROWS FROM` construct or the updated `unnest()` which takes multiple arrays to unnest in parallel.  Each can have a different length. You get ([per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS)):

> [...] the number of result rows in this case is that of the largest function
> result, with smaller results padded with null values to match.

Use this cleaner and simpler variant:

```
SELECT ARRAY[a,b] AS ab
FROM   unnest('{a,b,c}'::text[] 
            , '{d,e,f}'::text[]) x(a,b);
```

### Postgres 9.3 or older

#### Simple zip()

Consider the following demo for Postgres **9.3 or earlier**:

```
SELECT ARRAY[a,b] AS ab
FROM  (
   SELECT unnest('{a,b,c}'::text[]) AS a
        , unnest('{d,e,f}'::text[]) AS b
    ) x;
```

Result:

```
  ab
-------
 {a,d}
 {b,e}
 {c,f}
```

Note that both arrays must have the **same number of elements** to unnest in parallel, or you get a cross join instead.

You can wrap this into a function, if you want to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zip(anyarray, anyarray)
  RETURNS SETOF anyarray LANGUAGE SQL AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY[a,b] FROM (SELECT unnest($1) AS a, unnest($2) AS b) x;
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT zip('{a,b,c}'::text[],'{d,e,f}'::text[]);
```

Same result.

#### zip() to multi-dimensional array:

Now, if you want to **aggregate** that new set of arrays into one **2-dimenstional** array, it gets more complicated.

```
SELECT ARRAY (SELECT ...)
```

or:

```
SELECT array_agg(ARRAY[a,b]) AS ab
FROM  (
   SELECT unnest('{a,b,c}'::text[]) AS a
         ,unnest('{d,e,f}'::text[]) AS b
    ) x
```

or:

```
SELECT array_agg(ARRAY[ARRAY[a,b]]) AS ab
FROM  ...
```

will all result in the same error message (tested with pg 9.1.5):

> ERROR:  could not find array type for data type text[]

But there is a way around this, as we worked out under [this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9832973/939860).
Create a custom aggregate function:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult (anyarray) (
   SFUNC    = array_cat
 , STYPE    = anyarray
 , INITCOND = '{}'
);
```

And use it like this:

```
SELECT array_agg_mult(ARRAY[ARRAY[a,b]]) AS ab
FROM  (
   SELECT unnest('{a,b,c}'::text[]) AS a
        , unnest('{d,e,f}'::text[]) AS b
    ) x
```

Result:

```
{{a,d},{b,e},{c,f}}
```

Note the additional `ARRAY[]` layer! Without it and just:

```
SELECT array_agg_mult(ARRAY[a,b]) AS ab
FROM ...
```

You get:

```
{a,d,b,e,c,f}
```

Which may be useful for other purposes.

Roll another function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zip2(anyarray, anyarray)
  RETURNS SETOF anyarray LANGUAGE SQL AS
$func$
SELECT array_agg_mult(ARRAY[ARRAY[a,b]])
FROM (SELECT unnest($1) AS a, unnest($2) AS b) x;
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT zip2('{a,b,c}'::text[],'{d,e,f}'::text[]); -- or any other array type
```

Result:

```
{{a,d},{b,e},{c,f}}
```

Comment: In PostgreSQL 9.3 and above it'll be possible to rewrite this to use the SQL-standard `LATERAL` instead of PostgreSQL's sometimes "interesting" set-returning-functions-in-select-list feature. Until then, beware when using arrays of different lengths, you might be surprised by the results.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Right. For the purpose of this question, the OP defined arrays `of the same length`, though.

Comment: Yep, just making sure it's noted, because others who find this might not. Personally I'd write it in PL/PgSQL and add a sanity check.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another approach that's safe for arrays of differing lengths, using the array multi-aggregation mentioned by Erwin:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION zip(array1 anyarray, array2 anyarray) RETURNS text[]
AS $$
SELECT array_agg_mult(ARRAY[ARRAY[array1[i],array2[i]]])
FROM generate_subscripts(
  CASE WHEN array_length(array1,1) >= array_length(array2,1) THEN array1 ELSE array2 END,
  1
) AS subscripts(i)
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

regress=> SELECT zip('{a,b,c}'::text[],'{d,e,f}'::text[]);
         zip         
---------------------
 {{a,d},{b,e},{c,f}}
(1 row)


regress=> SELECT zip('{a,b,c}'::text[],'{d,e,f,g}'::text[]);
             zip              
------------------------------
 {{a,d},{b,e},{c,f},{NULL,g}}
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT zip('{a,b,c,z}'::text[],'{d,e,f}'::text[]);
             zip              
------------------------------
 {{a,d},{b,e},{c,f},{z,NULL}}
(1 row)
```

If you want to chop off the excess rather than null-padding, just change the `>=` length test to `<=` instead.

This function does *not* handle the rather bizarre PostgreSQL feature that arrays may have a stating element other than 1, but in practice nobody actually uses that feature. Eg with a zero-indexed 3-element array:

```
regress=> SELECT zip('{a,b,c}'::text[], array_fill('z'::text, ARRAY[3], ARRAY[0]));
          zip           
------------------------
 {{a,z},{b,z},{c,NULL}}
(1 row)
```

wheras Erwin's code *does* work with such arrays, and even with multi-dimensional arrays (by flattening them) but does *not* work with arrays of differing length.

Arrays are a bit special in PostgreSQL, they're a little too flexible with multi-dimensional arrays, configurable origin index, etc.

In 9.4 you'll be able to write:

```
SELECT array_agg_mult(ARRAY[ARRAY[a,b])
FROM unnest(array1) WITH ORDINALITY as (o,a)
NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN
unnest(array2) WITH ORDINALITY as (o,b);
```

which will be a lot nicer, especially if an optimisation to scan the functions together rather than doing a sort and join goes in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you're not a fan of using the Array datatype in Postgres?

Comment: @dan On the contrary, it's *extremely* useful, particularly as an intermediate result in complex queries and as an optimisation. It's just that the way arrays are implemented in Pg makes their behaviour a little ... surprising ... at times. Arrays with configurable starting indexes, multi-dimensional arrays under a single array type, etc. I just wish there was a more conventional simplified array type.

Comment: Nice add and interesting bit of news from pg 9.4. BTW.: One can use `arr_var[-2147483648:2147483647]` to "normalize" array subscripts;  [by courtesy of Daniel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-for-1-dimensional-array-so-they-start-with-1).