# Pairwise array sum aggregate function?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table with arrays as one column, and I want to sum the array elements together:

```
> create table regres(a int[] not null);
> insert into regres values ('{1,2,3}'), ('{9, 12, 13}');
> select * from regres;
     a
-----------
 {1,2,3}
 {9,12,13}
```

I want the result to be:

```
{10, 14, 16}
```

that is: `{1 + 9, 2 + 12, 3 + 13}`.

Does such a function already exist somewhere? The `intagg` extension looked like a good candidate, but such a function does not already exist.

The arrays are expected to be between 24 and 31 elements in length, all elements are `NOT NULL`, and the arrays themselves will also always be `NOT NULL`. All elements are basic `int`. There will be more than two rows per aggregate. All arrays will have the same number of elements, in a query. Different queries will have different number of elements.

My implementation target is: PostgreSQL 9.1.13

Comment: Also posted to pgsql-general mailing list: [Pairwise array sum aggregate function?](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BFABC9D5-D791-428E-95B9-8DB690E74711@teksol.info)

Comment: If you can live with some excessive typing: `select array[sum(a[1]), sum(a[2]), sum(a[3]), sum(a[4]), ....] from regres;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I hadn't thought of that. Excellent thinking outside of the box. I generate the query, so it's not really a problem to write such a select clause.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**General solutions** for any number of arrays with any number of elements. Individual elements or the the whole array can be NULL, too:

#### Simpler in 9.4+ using [`WITH ORDINALITY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html)

```sql
SELECT ARRAY (
   SELECT sum(elem)
   FROM  tbl t
       , unnest(t.arr) WITH ORDINALITY x(elem, rn)
   GROUP BY rn
   ORDER BY rn
   );
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

#### Postgres 9.3+

This makes use of an implicit [`LATERAL JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html)

```sql
SELECT ARRAY (
   SELECT sum(arr[rn])
   FROM   tbl t
        , generate_subscripts(t.arr, 1) AS rn
   GROUP  BY rn
   ORDER  BY rn
   );
```

See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

#### Postgres 9.1

```sql
SELECT ARRAY (
   SELECT sum(arr[rn])
   FROM  (
      SELECT arr, generate_subscripts(arr, 1) AS rn
      FROM   tbl t
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY rn
   ORDER  BY rn
   );
```

The same works in later versions, but *set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list* are not standard SQL and were frowned upon by some. Should be OK since Postgres 10, though. See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=28f17ec272ac2f05665d44a2f7a0da78)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/09a4c/1)</sub>

Related:

- [Is there something like a zip() function in PostgreSQL that combines two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414750/is-there-something-like-a-zip-function-in-postgresql-that-combines-two-arrays/12414884#12414884)

Comment: nice usage of lateral join

Comment: Thank you, but I'm on 9.1. I have plans to migrate later this year, but in the meantime, can something similar be achieved for 9.1?

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil: Added a version for 9.1.

Answer (score 4):

If you need better performances and can install Postgres extensions, the [agg_for_vecs](https://github.com/pjungwir/aggs_for_vecs) C extension provides a `vec_to_sum` function that should meet your need. It also offers various aggregate functions like `min`, `max`, `avg`, and `var_samp` that operate on arrays instead of scalars.

Answer (score 4):

I know the original question and answer are pretty old, but for others who find this... The most elegant and flexible solution I've found is to create a custom aggregate function. Erwin's answer presents some great simple solutions if you only need the single resulting array, but doesn't translate to a solution that could include other table columns and aggregations, in a `GROUP BY` for example.

With a custom `array_add` function and `array_sum` aggregate function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_add(_a numeric[], _b numeric[])
  RETURNS numeric[]
AS
$$
BEGIN
  RETURN ARRAY(
    SELECT coalesce(a, 0) + coalesce(b, 0)
    FROM unnest(_a, _b) WITH ORDINALITY AS x(a, b, n)
    ORDER BY n
  );
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE AGGREGATE array_sum(numeric[])
(
  sfunc = array_add,
  stype = numeric[],
  initcond = '{}'
);
```

Then (using the names from your example):

```
SELECT array_sum(a) a_sums
FROM regres;
```

Returns your array of sums, and it can just as well be used anywhere other aggregate functions could be used, so if your table also had a column `name` you wanted to group by, and another array of numbers, column `b`:

```
SELECT name, array_sum(a) a_sums, array_sum(b) b_sums
FROM regres
GROUP BY name;
```

You won't get quite the performance you'd get out of the built-in `sum` function and just selecting `sum(a[1]), sum(a[2]), sum(a[3])`, you'd have to implement the `array_add` function as a compiled C function to get that. But in cases where you don't have the ability to add custom C functions (like a managed cloud database, e.g. AWS RDS), or you're not aggregating huge numbers of rows, the difference probably won't be noticed.