# How to cast entity to set in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series, set-returning-functions

Using Postgres 9.3, I found out that I can perform something like this:

```
SELECT generate_series(1,10);
```

But I can't do this:

```
SELECT (SELECT generate_series(1,10));
```

Can I somehow cast SELECT result to `setof int` to use it same as result from `generate_series()`?

What exactly is happening there why I can use result from function but not from `SELECT`?

Comment: Came up with the crazy idea: `SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY(SELECT generate_series(1,10)));` Someone has better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first form is a non-standard feature of Postgres. It allows SRF (Set Returning Functions) in the `SELECT` list, which are expanded to multiple rows:

- [Is there something like a zip() function in PostgreSQL that combines two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414750/is-there-something-like-a-zip-function-in-postgresql-that-combines-two-arrays/12414884#12414884)

Note: that's working for ***functions***, not for sub-selects. That's why your second `SELECT` is simply invalid syntax.

Standard SQL does not have a provision for that at all, so the feature is frowned upon by some and clean alternatives have been provided (thanks to improvements in the SQL standard). It is largely superseded by the `LATERAL` feature in Postgres 9.3+:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

The simple form can be replaced by:

```
SELECT g
FROM   generate_series(1,10) g;
```

Whenever possible move SRF to the `FROM` clause and treat them like tables - since version 9.3 that's almost always possible.

Note that `g` serves as table *and* column alias automatically in the example. `g` in `SELECT g` binds to a column name first. More explicit syntax:

```
SELECT g
FROM   generate_series(1,10) AS t(g);  -- table_alias(column_alias)
```

You need to understand the difference between a *row*, a *set of rows* (~ a table) and an *array*. This would give you an *array* of integer:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT g FROM generate_series(1,10) g) AS g_arr;
```

Browse the tags [generate-series](/questions/tagged/generate-series) and [set-returning-functions](/questions/tagged/set-returning-functions) for many related answers with code examples.

Comment: But how result from SELECT is different from result from generate_series?

Comment: @Logman: Postgres has the non-standard feature to allow SRF (functions!) in the `SELECT` list (which is currently being phased out and replaced by standard-conforming syntax). It does not allow (and never has allowed) sub-selects in the `SELECT` list, though,  that return more than one row or more than one column.

Comment: I know that you want to convince me to use sets after FROM and I am actually using it like that. But for academic reasons I would like to add this specific functions functionality to SELECT. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: @Logman: No. As I explain above: In the `SELECT` list, a set-returning *function* can return multiple rows with a single value each, but a *sub-select* can only return a *single* value.