# Change a date range into new rows with discrete dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series, set-returning-functions

I have a table which contains `name`, `location`, `start_date`, and `end_date`. I am looking to transform these rows containing date ranges to rows of discrete dates while keeping corresponding row information intact.

Example:

```
Name1, Location1, 2015-4-01, 2015-4-04
```

Becomes:

```
Name1, Location1, 2015-4-01
Name1, Location1, 2015-4-02
Name1, Location1, 2015-4-03
Name1, Location1, 2015-4-04
```

I imagine that I'll need to create this as a new table using PostgreSQL functions.

Comment: Please always provide your version of Postgres. A table definition would be helpful, too. Can columns be NULL? Etc.

Comment: Noted! Thanks Erwin!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new table with the three required columns:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl (
  nam    varchar,
  loc    varchar,
  dt     date);
```

Since you want to have records in the new table over the range `start_date` - `end_date` with a day interval, inclusive, the easiest solution is to generate a set from your dates:

```
generate_series(start_date::timestamp, end_date::timestamp, '1 day')
```

This you can simply stick into an `INSERT` statement on the new table:

```
INSERT INTO new_tbl
  SELECT nam, loc, generate_series(start_date::timestamp, end_date::timestamp, '1 day')::date
  FROM old_tbl;
```

Since the `generate_series` function works with `timestamp` parameters, you need to explicitly cast your `date`s and then cast the generated `timestamp`s back to `date`s to match your column definition.

Answer (score 3):

In modern Postgres (9.3+) it's best to use set-returning functions in a `LATERAL` join in the `FROM` list:

Assuming `start_date` and `end_date` are defined `NOT NULL`:

```
CREATE TABLE AS
SELECT name, location, day::date
FROM   tbl, generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 day') day;
```

`LATERAL` is implicit here.
[The manual about `LATERAL` subqueries.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL)

Some related answers (there are many):

- [Generate_series in Postgres from start and end date in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023336/generate-series-in-postgres-from-start-and-end-date-in-a-table/29023639#29023639)
- [Calculate working hours between 2 dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839319/calculate-working-hours-between-2-dates-in-postgresql/17282639#17282639)

About `LATERAL` (in reply to comment):

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [How to cast entity to set in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266039/how-to-cast-entity-to-set-in-postgresql/29266170#29266170)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Comment: When you say "it's best to use set-returning functions in a LATERAL join", do you mean that that is the preferred way of doing things, or is there a performance / portability / etc issue here?

Comment: @Patrick: Set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list are a totally non-standard Postgres extension. They work fine for simple cases but exhibit dubious behavior when combining multiple instances or in some corner cases. `LATERAL` is standard SQL syntax and provides clean solutions for all combinations. It allows new features like `WITH ORDINALITY`. Performance for basic cases is similar. I added some links to the answer.