# Cumulative adding with dynamic base in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, aggregate, window-functions

I have the following scenario in Postgres (I'm using **9.4.1**).

I have a table of this format:

```
create table test(
    id serial,
    val numeric not null,
    created timestamp not null default(current_timestamp),
    fk integer not null
);
```

What I then have is a `threshold numeric` field in another table which should be used to label each row of `test`. For every value which is `>= threshold` I want to have that record marked as `true` but if it is `true` it should reset subsequent counts to 0 at that point, e.g.

Data set:

```
insert into test(val, created, fk)
  (100, now() + interval '10 minutes', 5),
  (25,  now() + interval '20 minutes', 5),
  (30,  now() + interval '30 minutes', 5),
  (45,  now() + interval '40 minutes', 5),
  (10,  now() + interval '50 minutes', 5);
```

With a threshold of 50 I would like to get the output as:

```
100 -> true (as 100 > 50) [reset]
25  -> false (as 25 < 50)
30  -> true (as 25 + 30 > 50) [reset]
45  -> false (as 45 < 50)
10  -> true (as 45 + 10 > 50)
```

Is it possible to do this in a single SQL query? So far I have experimented with using a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html).

```
select t.*,
       sum(t.val) over (
         partition by t.fk order by t.created
       ) as threshold_met
from test t
where t.fk = 5;
```

As you can see I have got it to the point where I have a cumulative frequency and suspect that the tweaking of `rows between x preceding and current row` may be what I'm looking for. I just can't work out how to perform the reset, i.e. set `x`, in the above to the appropriate value.

Comment: Excellent question with all the necessary details. More questions like this one please. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Create your own aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html), which can be used as window function.

### Specialized aggregate function

It's easier than one might think:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sum_cap50 (numeric, numeric)
  RETURNS numeric LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT CASE WHEN $1 > 50 THEN 0 ELSE $1 END + $2';

CREATE AGGREGATE sum_cap50 (numeric) (
  sfunc    = f_sum_cap50
, stype    = numeric
, initcond = 0
);
```

Then:

```
SELECT *, sum_cap50(val) OVER (PARTITION BY fk
                               ORDER BY created) > 50 AS threshold_met 
FROM   test
WHERE  fk = 5;
```

Result exactly as requested.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2fadd2b8320e480a73f516d81a49ce1e)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/78ea6/1)</sub>

### Generic aggregate function

To make it work for **any thresholds** and **any (numeric) data type**, and also **allow `NULL` values**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sum_cap (anyelement, anyelement, anyelement)
  RETURNS anyelement
  LANGUAGE sql STRICT AS
$$SELECT CASE WHEN $1 > $3 THEN '0' ELSE $1 END + $2;$$;

CREATE AGGREGATE sum_cap (anyelement, anyelement) (
  sfunc    = f_sum_cap
, stype    = anyelement
, initcond = '0'
);
```

Then, to call with a limit of, say, 110 with any numeric type:

```
SELECT *
     , sum_cap(val, '110') OVER (PARTITION BY fk
                                 ORDER BY created) AS capped_at_110
     , sum_cap(val, '110') OVER (PARTITION BY fk
                                 ORDER BY created) > 110 AS threshold_met 
FROM   test
WHERE  fk = 5;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=76b82aac29662328ed93da338f4c445e)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b8894/2)</sub>

#### Explanation

In your case we don't have to defend against **`NULL`** values since `val` is defined `NOT NULL`. If `NULL` can be involved, define `f_sum_cap()` as **`STRICT`** and it works because ([per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html)):

> If the state transition function is declared "strict", then it cannot
> be called with null inputs. With such a transition function, aggregate
> execution behaves as follows. Rows with any null input values are
> ignored (the function is not called and the previous state value is
> retained) [...]

Both function and aggregate take one more argument. For the [polymorphic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) variant it can be a hard coded data type or the same polymorphic type as the leading arguments.

About polymorphic functions:

- [Initial array in function to aggregate multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832973/initial-array-in-function-to-aggregate-multi-dimensional-array/9845460#9845460)

Note the use of **untyped string literals**, not numeric literals, which would default to `integer`!

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Erwin. One question: is it possible to define the threshold at runtime (as it will not always be 50)? Thanks :-)

Comment: Ah I think I've got it, I have changed the `f_sum_cap` function to take an additional `numeric` parameter which I pass through at query time, e.g. `sum_cap(val, 40)` and then have the `f_sum_cap` function use `'select case when $1 > $3 then 0 else $1 end + $2'`. Is this the best approach?

Comment: @jabclab: Basically yes. While being at it, I would also make it polymorphic and fit for NULL values. Consider the update.