# Iterating over integer[] in PL/pgSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, loops, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

I am trying to loop through an integer array (`integer[]`) in a plpgsql function. Something like this:

```sql
declare
  a integer[] = array[1,2,3];
  i bigint;
begin
  for i in a loop 
    raise notice "% ",i;
  end loop;
  return true;
end
```

In my actual use case the integer array `a` is passed as parameter to the function. I get this error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
> LINE 1:   $1

How to loop through the array properly?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Postgres **9.1** added [**`FOREACH`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) to loop over arrays:

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _arr  int[] := '{1,2,3,4}';
   _elem int;                      -- matching element type
BEGIN
   FOREACH _elem IN ARRAY _arr
   LOOP 
      RAISE NOTICE '%', _elem;
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d4f7e7d0e5ee1b2d9db3a48b175ff353)*

Works for multi-dimensional arrays, too: Postgres flattens the array and iterates over all elements. To loop over slices, see link below.

For older versions:

```sql
   FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(_arr, 1)  -- "i" is the index
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE '%', _arr[i];       -- single quotes
   END LOOP;
```

For **multi-dimensional arrays** and looping over **array slices** see:

- [Loop over array dimension in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783422/loop-over-array-dimension-in-plpgsql/9784986#9784986)

However, set-based solutions with [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) or [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) are often faster than looping over big sets. Basic examples:

- [PostgreSQL: Frequency Table Expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327046/postgresql-frequency-table-expansion/12327440#12327440)
- [Select each month between a start and end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747695/select-each-month-between-a-start-and-end-date/10747820#10747820)

Comment: right now I am passing the array to the function as `f(array[1,2,3,4])` is there any better way to pass an array to a function ?

Comment: `f('{1,2,3,4}'::int[])` is *another* way. Better? - you decide!

Comment: DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _arr  int[] := '{558, 588, 589, 578, 587, 580, 3808, 594, 560, 3801, 3803, 3840, 3841, 3842, 600, 3810, 590, 593, 3802, 3806, 3811, 555, 551, 557, 579, 553, 3804}';
   _elem int;                      -- matching element type
BEGIN
   FOREACH _elem IN ARRAY _arr
   LOOP 
      EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS threedeeinventorysync.partition_location_%;', _elem;
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
I tried to execute sql. its error
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: query returned 2 columns
  Where: query: 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS threedeeinventorysync.partition_location_%;', _elem

Comment: @user3534759: You've mixed the syntax for `format()` and `EXECUTE` in illegal ways. Proper syntax: `EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS threedeeinventorysync.%I;', 'partition_location_' || _elem);` Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12082038/939860

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FOREACH` statement to iterate the 1D array of `INT[]` as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  temp INT;
  _1d_arr INT[] := ARRAY[1,2,3];
BEGIN
  FOREACH temp SLICE 0 IN ARRAY _1d_arr LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', temp;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Or, you can use a `FOR` statement to iterate the 1D array of `INT[]` as shown below:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  _1d_arr INT[] := ARRAY[1,2,3];
BEGIN
  FOR num IN 1..3 LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', _1d_arr[num];
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Then, you can iterate the 1D array of `INT[]` as shown below:

```
INFO:  1
INFO:  2
INFO:  3
DO
```