# Select each month between a start and end date

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, date, select

Say I have a `startdate = '2010/04/01'` and an `enddate = '2011/02/01'`.

How would I set up a query such that I retrieve the following table as a response:

```
month
2010/04/01
2010/05/01
2010/06/01
2010/07/01
2010/08/01
2010/09/01
2010/10/01
2010/11/01
2010/12/01
2011/01/01
2011/02/01
```

Note that I'm not too fussed about the format, anything that works will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL has [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) to make that an easy task:

```
SELECT generate_series('2010-04-01', '2011-02-01', interval '1 month')::date
```