# PostgreSQL: Frequency Table Expansion

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

Does anyone know how to expand a frequency table in PostgreSQL?

For example, transform table x:

```
data   | frequency
-------+-----------
string |         4
```

into

```
data   | index 
-------+-------
string |     1
string |     2
string |     3
string |     4
```

Set up code:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
  data TEXT,
  frequency INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO x VALUES ('string',4);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is amazingly simple with [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES):

```
SELECT data, generate_series(1, frequency) AS index
FROM   x;
```