# Modify COALESCE function to consider two adjacent values for the result

Tags: postgresql, null, case, coalesce, greenplum

I'm currently using the `COALESCE` function to grab the first NOT NULL value from a list of fields. Example:

```
 COALESCE(header_to_node_13.subsetname, header_to_node_12.subsetname,
 header_to_node_11.subsetname, header_to_node_10.subsetname, 
 header_to_node_9.subsetname, header_to_node_8.subsetname, 
 header_to_node_7.subsetname, header_to_node_6.subsetname,   
 header_to_node_5.subsetname, header_to_node_4.subsetname,
 header_to_node_3.subsetname, header_to_node_2.subsetname,     
 header_to_node_1.subsetname, 
 header_to_node.subsetname, header_to_node.setname) AS prctr1
```

I need to modify the logic so that I grab the value to the right of the `COALESCE` value as well, so the two values can be compared to populate a newly created field.

For instance, if the `COALESCE` value is `header_to_node_5.subsetname` I need to grab `header_to_node_4.subsetname`, as well, so the two can be used in a `CASE` statement.

If the second value (`header_to_node_4.subsetname`) IS NULL I want the first value (`header_to_node_5.subsetname`). If the second value is NOT NULL I want to use the second value.

I'm stumped on how to grab the second value. I am using Greenplum/PostgreSQL 8.2

Comment: Using [massive CASE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/379240).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your requirement correctly you have an ordered set of fields, possibly coming from joining together several tables, and you want to obtain the first non-null field *and* the field immediately following it.

In this case you can use [**`LATERAL`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html): this allows you to reference fields provided by preceding `FROM` items:

```
SELECT id, COALESCE(t.b, t.a) AS result
FROM mytable,
LATERAL (
  SELECT x.v, LEAD(x.v) OVER (ORDER BY x.i) 
  FROM (
    VALUES (header_to_node_13, 1), (header_to_node_12, 2),
           (header_to_node_11, 3), (header_to_node_10, 4),
           (header_to_node_9, 5), (header_to_node_8, 6),
           (header_to_node_7, 7), (header_to_node_6, 8),
           (header_to_node_5, 9), (header_to_node_4, 10),
           (header_to_node_3, 11), (header_to_node_2, 12),
           (header_to_node_1, 13)) AS x(v,i)
  ORDER BY 
     CASE WHEN x.v IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
     x.i
  LIMIT 1 ) AS t(a, b)
```

Using `VALUES` inside the `LATERAL` subquery essentially constructs a table containing all fields referenced by the `COALESCE` function of your query. An order field, `x.i`, is also included in `VALUES` so as to define field order.

Once this in-line table is set-up you can easily perform an `ORDER BY`, together with `LIMIT 1`, on all fields so as to find the first non-null field. `LEAD` window function is used to get next field.

**Note:** For the sake of simplicity I have renamed fields present in the OP, e.g. `header_to_node_13.subsetname` to `header_to_node_13`. Also I have omitted some of the fields inside `COALESCE`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fd071/6)

Comment: This looks great. Unfortunately the LATERAL feature is unsupported in the version of PostgreSQL that I am using.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in Postgres 9.4 and up:

```
SELECT val, nextval
FROM
(
  SELECT
    val,
    lag(val) OVER w as prevval,
    lead(val) OVER w as nextval
  FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[
    header_to_node_13.subsetname, header_to_node_12.subsetname,
    header_to_node_11.subsetname, header_to_node_10.subsetname, 
    header_to_node_9.subsetname, header_to_node_8.subsetname, 
    header_to_node_7.subsetname, header_to_node_6.subsetname,   
    header_to_node_5.subsetname, header_to_node_4.subsetname,
    header_to_node_3.subsetname, header_to_node_2.subsetname,     
    header_to_node_1.subsetname, 
    header_to_node.subsetname, header_to_node.setname
  ]) WITH ORDINALITY AS u(val, pos)
  WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY pos)
) t
WHERE
  prevval IS NULL AND
  val IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the column names for clarity.

#### Function

For ***any input type*** and ***any number of values***, make it a [polymorphic](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) function taking a variable number of parameters ([`VARIADIC`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION coalesce2(VARIADIC ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS ANYELEMENT AS
$func$
BEGIN

FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper($1, 1)
LOOP
   IF $1[i] IS NOT NULL THEN
      RETURN COALESCE($1[i+1], $1[i]);
   END IF;
END LOOP;

RETURN NULL;  -- we only come this far if all values are NULL

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Call:

```
SELECT coalesce2(h13, h12, h11, h10, ...);
```

`VARIADIC` parameters are visible as one array inside the function and we can loop with `FOREACH`:

- [Iterating over integer[] in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214392/plpgsql-iterating-over-integer/10214621#10214621)

Or you could use a plain SQL function to encapsulate the logic of one of the following:

#### Pure SQL

```
SELECT COALESCE(lead(elem) OVER (ORDER BY ord), elem) AS result
FROM   unnest(ARRAY[h13, h12, h11, h10, ...]) WITH ORDINALITY u(elem, ord)
ORDER  BY elem IS NULL, ord
LIMIT  1;
```

`WITH ORDINALITY` (like [@Nick already displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33290538/939860)) requires Postgres **9.4** or later. This solution works as defined by the SQL standard. It's not strictly needed, though. This works, too:

```
SELECT COALESCE(lead(elem) OVER (), elem) AS result
FROM   unnest(ARRAY[h13, h12, h11, h10, ... ]) elem
ORDER  BY elem IS NULL
LIMIT  1;
```

It relies on the Postgres implementation of `unnest()` that preserves the order of array elements, and the window function `lead()` works with this given order, *before* the later `ORDER BY` reorders rows. Not strictly guaranteed by the SQL standard, but it works with all available versions of Postgres. Consider:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

You could also use a `VALUES` expression with manual numbering to be safe and standard-compliant like [@Giorgos demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33290346/939860) or with my simplified query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(lead(elem) OVER (), elem) AS result
FROM  (VALUES (h13), (h12), (h11), (h10), ... ) t(elem)
ORDER  BY elem IS NULL
LIMIT  1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/3932) demonstrating all.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 8.2 so I cannot use ORDINALITY. I tried the variadic function but it errors out:                                                                                       
    LINE 111:    COALESCE2(vw_header_to_node_13.subsetname,    
             ^
    HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types.                    You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @user3329160:Why would you still use the obsolete version 8.2? The fiddle demonstrates the the function works in modern Postgres.

Comment: Because it Greenplum specific, so EMC has their own version customized and  packaged with the system.

Comment: @user3329160: There is a tag for Greeplum - which is related to, but not exactly Postgres. Please always tag your questions accordingly.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way that this can be performed with the system that I'm working with?