# PostgreSQL: Iterating over array of text and executing SQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, procedure

I am copying tables from one schema to another. I am trying to pass argument of name of tables that I want to copy. But no table is created in Schema when I execute the CALL.

Command: `CALL copy_table('firstname', 'tableName1,tableName2,tableName3');`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE copy_table(user VARCHAR(50), strs TEXT)
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
DECLARE
    my_array TEXT;
BEGIN
    FOR my_array IN
        SELECT string_to_array(strs, ',')
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || user || '.' || my_array || ' (LIKE public.' || my_array || ' INCLUDING ALL)';
    END LOOP;
$$
```

Could you please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `string_to_array` returns an array value. Looping through arrays is performed by `FOREACH` command, not `FOR`.

See documentation:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY

```
CREATE FUNCTION sum(int[]) RETURNS int8 AS $$
DECLARE
  s int8 := 0;
  x int;
BEGIN
  FOREACH x IN ARRAY $1
  LOOP
    s := s + x;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN s;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over an array with `FOREACH` like Simon suggested. Or with `FOR` in old (or any) versions. See:

- [Iterating over integer[] in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214392/iterating-over-integer-in-pl-pgsql/10214621#10214621)

Typically, a set-based solution is shorter and faster, though:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE copy_tables(_schema text, VARIADIC _tables text[])
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE
   (SELECT string_agg(format('CREATE TABLE %1$I.%2$I (LIKE public.%2$I INCLUDING ALL)', _schema, t), E';\n')
    FROM   unnest(_tables) t);
END
$proc$;
```

About `VARIADIC`:

- [Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/return-rows-matching-elements-of-input-array-in-plpgsql-function/17978831#17978831)

Call, passing list of table names:

```
CALL copy_tables('firstname', 'tableName1', 'tableName2', 'tableName3');
```

Or, passing genuine array:

```
CALL copy_tables('foo', VARIADIC '{tableName1,tableName2,tableName3}');
```

Or, passing (and converting) comma-separated string (your original input):

```
CALL copy_tables('foo', VARIADIC string_to_array('tableName1,tableName2,tableName3', ','));
```

I use `format()` to concatenate the SQL string safely. Note that identifiers must be passed as **case-sensitive** strings! See:

- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)
- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49718/3684)