# Select substring from a varchar and convert to Integer array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.3

I have a VARCHAR of numbers inside my stored procedure, these numbers are organized as arrays, I will show an example below:

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3},{9} -- This is a STRING
```

I want to do a `FOR` loop to select every time a substring from this set between `{}` and convert this to an array of integers.

So at first time inside my loop I will have:

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

So I will use `array_to_string` to convert this to an `integer[]`

At second time I will have:

```
{1,2,3,4,5}
```

and keep going using `array_to_string`

Any tips? Careful, because unfortunately I'm using PostgreSQL 8.3!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do it in a single statement:

```
SELECT string_to_array(unnest(string_to_array(
          trim('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3},{9}', '{}')
          , '},{')), ',')::int[]
```

.. in Postgres 8.4 or later. [8.3 has reached EOL.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) Urgently consider an upgrade.

However, there is [`regexp_split_to_table()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-string.html) in 8.3 already:

```
SELECT string_to_array(regexp_split_to_table(
          trim('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3},{9}', '{}')
          , '},{'), ',')::int[]
```

[**-> SQLfiddle demo** for Postgres 8.3.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/d41d8/140)

For looping the array, consider this related answer:
[Postgres - array for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783422/postgres-array-for-loop/9784986#9784986)

Comment: Your solution is so elegant! But after that I need to iterate every element from each array to pass that number to another procedure like in the first array I will call my proc 9 times: my_proc(1); my_proc(2); my_proc(3); and keep going...

Comment: @ricardocaldeira: You can still do that after converting your data. I suppose a nested for loop. I added a link for looping arrays in modern and ancient Postgres ..

Comment: Man I was trying but I don't know how to get this... If you can help me please responde the other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480035/iterating-on-each-element-from-an-array-of-arrays-on-postgresql