# Iterating on each element from an array of arrays on Postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.3

I have a VARCHAR of numbers inside my stored procedure, these numbers are organized as arrays, I will show an example below:

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3},{9} -- This is a STRING
```

Now with a help from another guy from here I'm using this to get integer arrays `integer[]`

```
SELECT string_to_array(regexp_split_to_table(
      trim('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3},{9}', '{}')
      , '},{'), ',')::int[]
```

I will have a set of records, each of them with an array, see below:

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
{1,2,3,4,5}
{1,2,3}
{9}
```

I was trying but I cannot figure out how can I make a `FOR` to iterate over each element from these arrays to call another procecure to do with each element from each array.

An example for my array `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` that I will call `my_array`:

```
rec record;
arr integer[];

FOR rec IN SELECT string_to_array(unnest(string_to_array(trim(text_nodes_for_connectivity, '{}'), '},{')), ',')::int[] LOOP
    arr := array_cat(arr, rec);
END LOOP;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
function array_cat(integer[], record) does not exist
```

I need to convert each of my record results to an array, so I can use array_cat or another functions to iterate over array elements

My proc code goes below:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS clustering_nodes();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clustering_nodes() RETURNS integer[] AS $$

DECLARE
my_array integer[];
rec record;
arr integer[];
my_var varchar[500];
len integer;

BEGIN

my_var = '{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3},{8}';


FOR rec IN SELECT string_to_array(unnest(string_to_array(trim(my_var, '{}'), '},{')), ',')::int[] LOOP
    len = array_length(rec);
    arr := array_append(arr, len);
END LOOP;

RETURN arr;

END;

$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' STRICT;

select clustering_nodes();
```

Tips or triks?

Comment: Well, your `FOR` loop looks fine. We need more to pin down the problem. Error message, to begin with. The whole pgsql function including the header would be great, too.

Comment: I updated my question, so I want to loop in each record that SELECT returned to me and manipulate each of them as a independent array

Comment: `The whole pgsql function` *`including the header `* and the function call, too. Essential for your question.

Comment: attached my proc code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clustering_nodes()
  RETURNS integer[] AS
$func$
DECLARE
   my_var   text  := '{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3},{8}';
   my_array integer[];
   arr_len  integer[];
BEGIN

FOR my_array IN
   SELECT string_to_array(regexp_split_to_table(
            trim(my_var, '{}'), '},{'), ',')::int[]
LOOP
   arr_len := array_append(arr_len, array_upper(my_array, 1));
END LOOP;

RETURN arr_len;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Major points

- [`array_length()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) doesn't work on records, only on array.
  What's more, there is [no `array_length()` in Postgres 8.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE). The manual is instrumental in figuring that out yourself. Using the less favorable `array_upper()` instead.
- [Assignment operator in plpgsql is `:=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace). Use of `=` is undocumented.
- `plpgsql` is an identifier in `LANGUAGE plpgsql`, not a string. Do not quote it. May lead to sneaky errors.
- You can assign variables at declaration time.
- `STRICT` modifier is pointless without parameters.

[**-> SQLfiddle demo** for Postgres 8.3.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/39262/1)

#### Simpler with modern Postgres

Again, this could be had in a single (if somewhat complex) call:

```
SELECT array_agg(array_length(string_to_array(txt, ','), 1))
FROM   unnest(string_to_array(
          trim('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3},{8}', '{}')
          , '},{')
       ) AS sub(txt);
```

You need to upgrade to a current version.