# postgres9.4 loop through jsonb: how select vals of key:val pairs

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, multidimensional-array, jsonb

This plpgsql script selects the keys from a set of jsonb object key:value pairs, but how to select the value for each pair?

```
DO
$BODY$
DECLARE
    js jsonb := '{"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}';
    i text;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text(js)
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'key %', i;
    --RAISE NOTICE 'value %', i.value; <--fai
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Should be possible as man page http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html indicates return value is setof key text, value text. This post [Postgres - array for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783422/postgres-array-for-loop) answers the question for array.
Also tried jsonb_each() and jsonb_array_elements() changing iterator to jsonb, with error "Cannot extract element from an object"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you declared `i` as `text` it only contains the first column. Declare it as `RECORD`:

```
DO
$BODY$
DECLARE
    js jsonb := '{"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}';
    i record;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text(js)
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'key %', i.key;
    RAISE NOTICE 'value %', i.value;
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$;
```