# PL/pgSQL: PERFORM vs CALL

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql, procedure

While fiddling with the performance impact of calling a procedure from another procedure vs. repeating the code in Postgres 13, I found that you can invoke other procedures by using either `CALL` or `PERFORM`.

I googled for differences but the only similar thing I found was

- [PL/pgSQL perform vs execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920998/pl-pgsql-perform-vs-execute)

Which addresses `PERFORM` vs. `EXECUTE` and not `PERFORM` vs. `CALL`.

Does anyone know what the difference is? Which one should I use (when calling a procedure from a PL/pgSQL procedure)?

Comment: You can not use `perform` to call a stored procedure. The only way to call a procedure is to use `call` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f9682a6888fb157e2522f80294669996

Comment: You're right, my bad. I realized I'm using a void function, not a procedure. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[**`CALL`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html) is an **SQL command** to execute a **[`PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html)** and was added with Postgres 11, when SQL procedures were added. Example:

```
CALL my_procedure('arg1');
```

[**`SELECT`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) is the plain **SQL command** to execute a **[`FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html)**. Example:

```
SELECT my_function('arg1');
```

[**`PERFORM`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) is a **[PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) command** to replace the `SELECT` keyword (in an otherwise plain SQL `SELECT` command) and discard any result(s). Example:

```
...
BEGIN
   PERFORM my_function('arg1');
END
...
```

[**`EXECUTE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) is a **PL/pgSQL command** to execute a (dynamically generated) SQL string. Any complete SQL command is allowed, not just `SELECT`. Example:

```
...
BEGIN
   EXECUTE my_string_variable
   USING arg1;
END
...
```

The SQL string can contain `CALL` or `SELECT` or any other SQL command. But parameter symbols referencing the `USING` clause are only allowed as data elements in the DML commands `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, and `MERGE` (these symbols cannot be used in place of table names, etc.).

Results are discarded automatically unless an `INTO` clause is added.

---

You cannot `CALL` a function.
You cannot `SELECT` or `PERFORM` a procedure.
You cannot `PERFORM` an `EXECUTE`, or `EXECUTE` a `PERFORM`, neither being an SQL command.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0fc8420f4ee3eb57f6060ee36729b70b)*

Related:

- [PL/pgSQL perform vs execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920998/pl-pgsql-perform-vs-execute/42922661#42922661)
- [Looping through a given list of values in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251111/looping-through-a-given-list-of-values-in-pl-pgsql/42286802#42286802)