# Hasura - query has no destination for result data

Tags: postgresql, graphql, plpgsql, hasura

In Hasura, I'm trying write a plpgsql based function which should return the t_documents. The function should accept various optional arguments, based on the argument values it should run appropriate SQL (using IF conditional checks) and return the records. This is my goal.

I've started with simple function with no arguments, the function created and tracked successfully in Hasura, however when try to query it throws `"query has no destination for result data"`

Any help to achieve the goal is highly appreciated

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dms.fngetdocs()
 RETURNS SETOF dms.t_documents
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 STABLE
AS $function$
BEGIN
SELECT *
    FROM dms.t_documents;
END;    
$function$
```

Comment: since you are `SELECT`-ing from a table, you need to put the results somewhere and `RETURN` those results at the end of the function

Comment: Change to `LANGUAGE SQL` and your function will work. More extended answer from Erwin Brandstetter https://stackoverflow.com/a/69138809/1168212

Answer (score 2):

Every SQL statement returning rows (like `SELECT`, but also `INSERT` with `RETURNING` etc.) must have a target for the resulting data. That's what the error message tells you. Either assign variables or return to the caller. To *discard* results instead, use `PERFORM` instead of `SELECT`. See:

- [SELECT raises exception in PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230750/select-raises-exception-in-pl-pgsql-function/37234043#37234043)
- [PL/pgSQL: PERFORM vs CALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67709708/pl-pgsql-perform-vs-call/67711519#67711519)
- [SELECT or PERFORM in a PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115806/select-or-perform-in-a-pl-pgsql-function/10117015#10117015)

But you obviously want to return rows. Your PL/pgSQL function would work like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dms.fngetdocs()
  RETURNS SETOF dms.t_documents
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT * FROM dms.t_documents;
END
$func$
```

See:

- [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)

Makes very little sense, of course. Instead of calling that function you would just use `SELECT * FROM dms.t_documents;` directly.

Or use a simpler SQL function, where the result of a `SELECT` is returned automatically:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dms.fngetdocs()
  RETURNS SETOF dms.t_documents
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT * FROM dms.t_documents;
$func$;
```

[See the manual about the added `PARALLEL SAFE`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/parallel-safety.html)