# Looping in PL/pgSQL to insert rows from multiple unnested arrays?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create 3 arrays, iterate through each, and insert records depending on the value of those iterations. My code is as follows:

```
do $$
  declare 
    days integer[];
    times time[];
    durations integer[];
  begin
    days := array[1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    times := array['00:00:00',
      '00:00:00',
      '01:00:00',
      '02:00:00',
      '03:00:00',
      '04:00:00',
      '05:00:00',
      '06:00:00',
      '07:00:00',
      '08:00:00',
      '09:00:00',
      '10:00:00',
      '11:00:00',
      '12:00:00',
      '13:00:00',
      '14:00:00',
      '15:00:00',
      '16:00:00',
      '17:00:00',
      '18:00:00',
      '19:00:00',
      '20:00:00',
      '21:00:00',
      '22:00:00',
      '23:00:00'
    ];
    durations := array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 24];
    FOR day IN days LOOP
      FOR time IN times LOOP
        FOR duration IN durations LOOP
          INSERT INTO public.pricing(id, site_id, start_time, price, day_of_week, booking_duration, inserted_at, updated_at) VALUES (10_000_000_000_000, 9999, time, 1000, day, duration, '2021-09-08 10:19:27.000000 +00:00', '2021-09-08 10:19:27.000000 +00:00');
        END LOOP;
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
  end;
$$;
```

When executing this I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "days"
LINE 35:     FOR day IN days LOOP
```

I've tried not using a variable:

```
FOR day IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) LOOP
```

But this throws the same error. I've tried following [Looping through a given list of values in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251111/looping-through-a-given-list-of-values-in-pl-pgsql) but can't see where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY):

```
FOREACH day IN ARRAY days LOOP
   ...
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unnest function to iterate over the result in a `FOR` loop using an ARRAY, for instance:

```sql
do $$
  declare 
    days integer[];
    times time[];
    durations integer[];
   day  int;
   time time;
   duration int;
  begin
    days := array[1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    times := array['00:00:00',
      '00:00:00',
      '01:00:00',
      '02:00:00',
      '03:00:00',
      '04:00:00',
      '05:00:00',
      '06:00:00',
      '07:00:00',
      '08:00:00',
      '09:00:00',
      '10:00:00',
      '11:00:00',
      '12:00:00',
      '13:00:00',
      '14:00:00',
      '15:00:00',
      '16:00:00',
      '17:00:00',
      '18:00:00',
      '19:00:00',
      '20:00:00',
      '21:00:00',
      '22:00:00',
      '23:00:00'
    ];
    durations := array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 24];
    FOR day IN select unnest(days) LOOP
      FOR time IN select unnest(times) LOOP
        FOR duration IN select unnest(durations) LOOP
         raise notice 'day: %, time: %, duration: %',day,time,duration;
       END LOOP;
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
  end;
$$;
```

you can use a [foreach](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) clause to iterate over an array as well

Answer (score 1):

If you actually need looping in PL/pgSQL consider [`FOREACH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY):

- [Iterating over integer[] in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214392/iterating-over-integer-in-pl-pgsql/10214621#10214621)
- [Loop over array dimension in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783422/loop-over-array-dimension-in-plpgsql/9784986#9784986)

But you don't. Just cross-join unnested arrays to get the Cartesian Product.

```sql
INSERT INTO public.pricing(id, site_id, start_time, price, day_of_week, booking_duration, inserted_at, updated_at)
SELECT (10_000_000_000_000, 9999, time, 1000 , day, duration, '2021-09-08 10:19:27+0', '2021-09-08 10:19:27+0')
FROM   unnest('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}'::int[]) AS day
     , unnest('{00:00,01:00,02:00,03:00,04:00,05:00,06:00,07:00
               ,08:00,09:00,10:00,11:00,12:00,13:00,14:00,15:00
               ,16:00,17:00,18:00,19:00,20:00,21:00,22:00,23:00}'::time[]) AS time
     , unnest('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,24}'::int[]) AS duration;
```

*Much* simpler and faster.

- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167217/3684)