# ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to create a small function that will return all the clients in an array but I keep bumping into errors.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    c_ids INTEGER[] := array[12879,16759];
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM   client
  WHERE  id IN (c_ids);
END $$;
```

What would be the right way to do something like this? I need the c_ids to be a variable because I will be using it in many places in the query (the sample straight forward query is not the end query).

Comment: Not a super pro at postgres but I believe you need to use curly braces for the data. This post is an example with a loop but I think it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783422/postgres-array-for-loop

Comment: @JacobH The curly braces are for writing an array as a string e.g. `'{1,2,3}'` vs `ARRAY[1,2,3]`. End result is the same.

Comment: @eurotrash Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IN` operator compares values using the `=` operator. If you want to check values in an array, you need to use `ANY`:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    c_ids INTEGER[] := array[12879,16759];
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM   client
  WHERE  id = ANY (c_ids);
END $$;
```